# PRAW Program not reading posts and comments correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code. Please note that it does not raise any errors, but does not work in the correct manner either.

```py
import praw
import time

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "This is a program to check if anyone is cursing on the forum.")
r.login("BottyMcFooFoo","991319")
curseWords = ['nigger','bitch','faggot','shit','shit','dick','cock'] #Excuse my foul mouth
alreadyScolded = []
scoldedPosts = 0
scoldedComments = 0
looped = 0
def run_botA():
    global looped
    global postText
    global commentText
    global postle
    global comment

    subreddit = r.get_subreddit("test")
    postle = subreddit.get_rising(limit = 20)

    comment = subreddit.get_comments(limit=20)
    for x in postle:
        postText = x.selftext.lower()
    for x in comment:
        commentText = x.body.lower()
    looped += 1
    print("Configuring settings")
    print()
    print()


def run_botB():
    global looped
    global postText
    global commentText
    global curseWords
    global postle
    global comment
    global alreadyScolded
    global scoldedPosts
    global scoldedComments
    for posts in postle:
        print("Checking posts for naughty language")
        print()
        print()
        has_praw = any(string in postText for string in curseWords)
        if has_praw == True and posts.id not in alreadyScolded:
            r.send_message("I am a bot, but you should watch your mouth young man/woman/fire hydrant(I dont mean to misgender)")
            alreadyScolded.append(posts.id)
            scoldedPosts += 1

    for comments in comment:
        print("Checking comments for naughty language")
        print()
        print()
        has_praw = any(string in commentText for string in curseWords)
        if has_praw == True and comments.id not in alreadyScolded:
            r.send_message("I am a bot, but you should watch your mouth young man/woman/fire hydrant(I dont mean to misgender)")
            alreadyScoled.append(posts.id)
            scoldedComments += 1
    print("Done %d loops." %(looped))
    print("Scolded %d posts and %d comments" %(scoldedPosts,scoldedComments))
    for x in range(10):
        print()


run_botA()
run_botB()            
input("Press enter to close m8!")
```

Comment: Please describe what is the problem and how did you try to solve it.

Comment: It doesn't read the posts or comments on the subreddit 'test'. I have tried by making a test post. I have tried to fix the problem by changing the way it checks for the curse words.

Comment: Please add the details to the question

Comment: Here is the code to just read the post:        https://repl.it/Ccj8/0

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, at least in part, your problem begins here:

```
for x in comment:
    commentText = x.body.lower()
```

This loop simply amounts to taking `commentText` to denote the lower-text of the *last* comment body. You probably wanted to aggregate the comments in a list:

```
comment_list = [x.body.lower() for x in comment]
```

Comment: Like comment_list.append(x.body)? or whatever the list name is

Comment: Possibly, yes. I will add an example